# Huge performance difference of a C++ program (compiled with GCC) under Mac and Linux

Tags: c++, performance, macos, gcc, operating-system

Recently I wrote a small program in C++ (well, to be really honest it's more C plus classes) and tested the performance on both a Mac and Linux machine.

Even though the hardware is comparable, the performance is so different than I really thing there is something strange going on.

First of all some details:

Input: about 200MB compressed data

Operations of the program: it decompresses the data, then loads it in memory, and perform many data access to perform joins between the data. The program is sequential (no additional threads or processes).

Output: some strings to be displayed on the screen

The code is compiled using GCC 4.8.1 in the Linux machine and GCC 4.8.2 in the Mac machine. In both cases the compiler is called with the arguments:

```
gcc -c -O3 -fPIC -MD -MF $(patsubst %.o,%.d,$@) //The last three arguments are to create the dependencies between the files
```

The Mac (OS=mac mavericks 10.9) machine is a macbook pro equipped with a 2,3 GHz Intel core I7 (it's a quadcore) 256KB L2 cache, 6MB L3 cache, 8GB of DDR3 1600Mhz, and a 256 GB SSD disk.

The Linux machine (kernel 2.6.32-358) has a Intel E5-2620 2.0 GHz (it's a sixcore) 16MB cache, 64GB of DDR3 1600Mhz, and a 256 GB SSD disk. Both machines should use the Sandy Bridge architecture (maybe the Mac is ivy bridge, but anyway this shouldn't make a big difference).

Now if I launch the program on the linux machine then it takes 217ms to finish while if I launch it in the Mac machine it takes 132ms: this makes the linux code 1.6 times slower!!

Now, I understand that the two machines have different OS and hardware, but I find a such slowdown too large to be justified by these factors, and I feel that there must be some other reason behind it.

Notice that this timings were being taken after all the data is loaded in memory, and I'm sure the program does not swap to disk during this time. Therefore, I can exclude that the problem is the SSD disk.

Now, I really don't know what could have caused such slowdown? The memory is basically equivalent, while the CPU is only a bit slower.

Could it be that GCC produced a sensibly worse code on a linux than a mac?

Could it be that the Linux OS is sensibly worse than the Mac?

I find both things hard to believe. Any help?

**EDIT:**

I realized that I didn't mention how I do the timings: well, I use the boost chrono library, and I measure only the time necessary to invoke the main function. Something like:

```
time = now();
function();
duration = now() - time;
print(duration);
```

**EDIT2:**
After some tests, we managed to reproduce the difference of performance with a much simpler (and silly) program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

char in1[10000000];
char in2[10000000];

static inline uint64_t rdtscp (void) {
    uint64_t low, high;
    uint64_t aux;

    __asm__ __volatile__ (
                    ".byte 0x0f,0x01,0xf9"
                    : "=a" (low), "=d" (high), "=c" (aux)
                    );

    return low | (high << 32);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    uint64_t counter = rdtscp();

    for(int i = 0; i < 10000000; ++i) {
            in1[i] = (char)i * 200;
            in2[i] = (char)i * 100;
    }

    int joins = 0;
    for(int j = 0; j < 10000000; ++j) {
            int el = in1[j];
            for(int m = 0; m < 10000000; m++) {
                    if (in2[m] == el) {
                            joins++;
                            break;
                    }
            }
    }
    printf("Joins %d Cycles total %ld\n", joins, (rdtscp() - counter));

    return 0;
}
```

Please don't look at the operations of the program. They make little sense. What we tried to reproduce is a sequence of access to memory and simple operations with them.

We launched this program on the Mac and the output was:

```
Joins 10000000 Cycles total 589015641
```

While on the linux machine it was:

```
Joins 10000000 Cycles total 838198832
```

Clearly the linux version requires many more CPU cycles, which are probably needed to access the memory. Now the question is: why is the memory access slower?

One reason could be that in1 and in2 don't fit in the CPU caches, and this requires some RAM accesses. As pointed by Roy Longbottom the memory in linux is indeed ECC and this could be the reason behing the lower performance. If we combine this with the slightly lower CPU speed, the difference between sandy and ivy bridge then we probably have a good explanation for such difference.

Anyway, thanks all for the tips!

Comment: How are you timing the program? Launch/finish or entry/exit to/from `main`? (it should be the latter)

Comment: How many strings is "some"?  If it's more than a few you might try redirecting the output to a file in case the output is slowing things down.  Honestly though, one taking a small fraction of a second less than the other probably isn't worth worrying too much about.  If you need to scale up to a larger dataset or a longer duration of work then it would likely be worth profiling on both to see if you can narrow it down.

Comment: My code has almost a 2x difference (in favor of the code compled and run on the Mac). I tried compiling and running my c++ code under linux (Ubuntu, CentOS) on very different hardware and in all the cases Linux is about 2x slower. Used the exactly the same optimization flags and the g++ compiler

Answer (score 2):

Both systems follow the System V AMD64 ABI, so gcc shouldn't make a difference there.  Unfortunately, random effects in system performance are rather prevalent nowadays, so you can sometimes get significant performance differences through things as silly as re-ordering link order (cf. Mytkowicz et al., ``Producing wrong data without doing anything obviously wrong'' , http://citeseer.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.163.8395)

Here are some suggestions for how to analyse this that come to mind:

1. Do more than one run.  Personally I take at least 11 runs and compare the median (as well as the various quartiles, but that's probably more than you may care about there).  This avoids some of the random effects.
2. Pipe all output into a file to minimise UI effects.
3. Check your performance counters.  On Linux you can use the `perf` tool.  Check for `major-faults`, which suggest that you have page faults that need to go to disk (unlikely on multiple runs, of course).  Only then can you exclude that the disk makes a difference there.  Unfortunately OS X doesn't (to the best of my knowledge) have as easy a way to collect performance counters.
4. You can experiment with `-mcpu` to force the same target instruction set.
5. Compare actual cache sizes.  `dmidecode -t cache` does that on the Linux side, but you must be root.  Your machines may have relevant differences there.
6. If your program runs through multiple phases, try benchmarking them individually.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Looking at it another way, the runtime difference is just 85 milliseconds, which is *tiny*.

What exactly are you measuring? If it's the whole programme runtime including startup and teardown (e.g. using the Unix `time` command) then the difference might easily be due to the dynamic linkers involved: on Linux at least, your programme will be linked to the system `libstdc++` before it's actually executed. If the MacOS dynamic linker is a tiny bit faster (or the programme gets statically linked on the Mac?), this could easily explain the difference.

Or it might even be the time taken to write to the terminal. On Linux, `gnome-terminal` for example is often seen as "slow" due to its use of anti-aliased fonts and full Unicode support. Does your programme run faster if you use `xterm` instead? What happens if you redirect the output to `/dev/null`?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if you account for the different frequency (which may be critical if your program is CPU-bound and not memory-bound, you haven't told us what your code does), than the difference is reduced to ~1.43.

However, if one of the CPUs is IvyBridge-based, there may be quite some differences. It's true that the architecture didn't change dramatically, but there are some changes that may not be apparent when benchmarking over a large set of applications, but could be critical on specific ones. In your case you haven't shown any code but since you're dealing with large memory structures it could be related to one of these

- **Adaptive fill policy** described [here](http://blog.stuffedcow.net/2013/01/ivb-cache-replacement/)
- **Dynamic prefetch throttling**, mentioned [here](http://www.itproportal.com/2012/04/24/intel-ivy-bridge-architecture-breakdown/).
- **Next-page prefetching**, mentioned [here](http://hexus.net/tech/reviews/cpu/37989-intel-core-i7-3770k-22nm-ivy-bridge/?page=2)

There aren't many details about the actual implementations but the reverse engineering done on the first is pretty impressive, and the second and third names speak for themselves (you could verify if this is the problem by disabling prefetces on both machines and comparing again). These features may be very critical on some memory consuming workloads (especially latency critical ones), but it's hard to tell without knowing how much you rely on your L3 cache

I'd also suggest making sure that you don't use OS-specific library versions or compiler version-specific intrinsics, the Apple folks may have done a better job in optimizing some basic operations

Answer (score 0):

I attempted to compile that code via Linux Ubuntu on my Core 2 Duo PC. I could not get rdtscp to work and used a CPU time counter instead. The program was compiled with just the -O3 option. The key part of the C program and assembly listing are shown below. This PC can select 2.4 GHz or 1.6 GHz with default on-demand to produce a varying performance (at anything between 1.6 and 2.4 GHz). Results at 1.6 and 2.4 GHz are shown below. I added and extra count (floating point), to discover what was happening.  Then speeds in  joins per second were no different.

The result in joins per second was proportional to CPU MHz, unlikely if main memory speed dependent. Increasing the array and loop counts by 10 and 100 times produced the same joins per second, suggesting that memory speed can be ignored.

So, we are left with relative GHz under Turbo Boost, the same machine code generated (notice aligns) and the effects of Sandy Bridge vs Ivy Bridge. With the extra counter, it is possible to count the number of assembly instructions executed - I got lost on counting.

```
    for(j = 0; j < 10000000; ++j) {
            int el = in1[j];
            for(m = 0; m < 10000000; m++) {
                    count = count + 1;
                    if (in2[m] == el) 
                    {
                            joins++;
                            break;
                    }
            }
    }

  .L6:
        movzbl  in1(%ecx), %edx
        xorl    %eax, %eax
        jmp     .L5
        .p2align 4,,7
        .p2align 3
  .L3:
        addl    $1, %eax
        cmpl    $10000000, %eax
        je      .L4
  .L5:
        cmpb    in2(%eax), %dl
        fadd    %st, %st(1)
        jne     .L3
        addl    $1, %ebx
  .L4:
        addl    $1, %ecx
        cmpl    $10000000, %ecx
        jne     .L6

 Result 2400 MHz
 Count  320000000  Joins 10000000  0.4920310 seconds  20.32M  joins per second
 Result 1600 MHz
 Count  320000000  Joins 10000000  0.7400470 seconds  13.51M  joins per second
```