# Why this code run so differently in Mac and Red Hat

Tags: c++, linux, macos, performance, gcc

This is a part of code using a list of trees to accumulate an array.It runs very slowly in Red Hat.

I loop this code,8860000 times.
mac consumes 13.6957 seconds.
Red hat consumes 50.78 seconds.

Why does mac run the same code significantly faster than Red hat with a slower cpu?
I list information of these two systems ,can anyone help me figure out?
The comand i use to compile is : g++ main.cc tp.cc -O2.
Compiler do has some difference,does mac air support float point calculation better than Red hat computer,anyway,please help me.

```
inline bool TP::left_branch(double const& fea_val, float const& node_val) {
  return fea_val <= node_val;
}   
void TP::predict(double const *features){
  uint32_t i, n, k;
  double* preds=predictions_;
  memcpy(preds, init_preds_, sizeof(double) * class_count_);

  for (i = 0; i < tree_count_; i++) {
    struct Tree *tree = trees_ + i;
    for (n = 0;;) {
      struct Node *node = tree->root + n;
      if (node->is_leaf) {
        //leaf_nodes[i] = node->leaf_idx;
        for (k = 0; k < class_count_; k++) {
          preds[k] += node->increments[k];
        }
        break;
      }
      if (left_branch(features[node->var_idx], node->var_val)) {
        n = n * 2 + 1;
      } else {
        n = n * 2 + 2;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Mac info:
mac      : OS X Yosemite 10.10 (14A389)
cpu      : 1.4 GHz Intel Core i5
compiler : Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.56) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0
Thread model: posix

Red Hat info:
pc       : Linux version 2.6.32-220.23.2.ali927.el5.x86_64
cpu      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2630 0 @ 2.30GHz
compile  : g++ (GCC) 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-51)

Comment: Have you run this code through a profiler on both systems? What are the differences in assembly code produced on the two systems?

Comment: Seems like `clang` just has a much better optimizer than `gcc`.

Comment: Try also with a newer version of GCC, yours hasn't been updated since years!

Comment: bear in mind red hat comes with a very old version of gcc

Comment: It takes 38s with  Linux version 3.13.0-24-generic (buildd@panlong) (gcc version 4.8.2 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) ) ,Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2630L 0 @ 2.00GHz.

Comment: Which tool can be used to detect differences in assembly code produced on two systems @wolfPack88

Comment: These two lines are most time-consuming. memcpy(preds, init_preds_, sizeof(double) * class_count_); left_branch(features[node->var_idx], node->var_val)

Comment: With GCC you can use the -S option to output assembly code. There should in clang, but I am not familiar with it, so I don't know what it is. After getting the two assembly codes, see what the difference is for the two lines you mentioned. If they are different, it is likely that one compiler is optimizing better than the other.

Comment: @jrbn,one year ago,you post a question about performance of code compiled under Mac and Linux. Have you find out the reason,  Sorry i don't have enough reputation to add a comment under your post.thank you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20187839/huge-performance-difference-of-a-c-program-compiled-with-gcc-under-mac-and-l?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of possible reasons, which I've listed in what I think is descending order of likelihood.

- **Very old compiler / OS versions:** You are running a *very* old version of g++ (over 7 years old) on an equally out of date Linux distro. It's quite possible that you are simply dealing with a big difference in code quality. You should consider updating your version of Red Hat (or another distro) to something more modern, not just because of performance but also because of security issues.
- **Locality due to memory allocator differences:** Another possible cause is differences in locality because of the memory allocator (malloc). You could try Hoard ([www.hoard.org](http://www.hoard.org)) or another replacement memory allocator on both systems to isolate that effect.
- **Hardware differences:** You are running on two quite different hardware platforms. While I do not suspect this is the issue, you can isolate possible hardware effects by running Linux in a VM on your Mac. Use something like Parallels or VMware, which have pretty high performance, and not VirtualBox, which does not.

Comment: It takes 38s with  Linux version 3.13.0-24-generic (buildd@panlong) (gcc version 4.8.2 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) ) ,Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2630L 0 @ 2.00GHz.

Comment: These two lines are most time-consuming.  memcpy(preds, init_preds_, sizeof(double) * class_count_);  left_branch(features[node->var_idx], node->var_val)

Comment: You forgot a few things: different compilers (his `g++` is obviously `clang`) and different C++ libraries (`libc++` vs `libstdc++`) while the later most probably doesn't matter for his code.

Comment: Tks @Thomas, my code do has link with c++ libraries, mac with libc++, linux with libstdc++ .Based on EmeryBerger 's analysis ，I have excluded the effect of compiler(4.8.2) and os(3.13.0), it still runs slower than mac. In your experiencies,  could libc++ work faster than libstdc++.